# Characterizing Fruit Harvest Timing in R with single statistical values

Tags: r

I am brand new to this so sorry if my question sounds simple. Here is my problem:

I am working on **Fruit Harvest timing data**, the goal is to get meaningful single values to compare the timing of different cultivars. Trees are harvested in several weeks so if you plot the yield of each cultivar per week you get something that could be assimilated to a normal distribution.

My idea is to **get statistical values for the distribution of harvest across the weeks**.

Values I am thinking about are **quartiles**, **IQR** (inter quartile range), **kurtosis**, **skewness**, etc... but I simply struggle to approach that in R.

My data are presented like this:

```
cultivar, week , year , yield
var x, week 10 , year 1 , 600 grams
var y, week 10 , year 1 , 850 grams
var x, week 13 , year 1 , 1000 grams
var y, week 14 , year 1 , 1200 grams
var x, week 15 , year 1 , 700 grams
var y, week 16 , year 1 , 1000 grams
var x, week 10 , year 2 , 500 grams
var y, week 10 , year 2 , 700 grams
var x, week 13 , year 2 , 1300 grams
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your dataframe looks like this

```
> df
  cultivar      week     year       yield
1    var x  week 10   year 1    600 grams
2    var y  week 10   year 1    850 grams
3    var x  week 13   year 1   1000 grams
4    var y  week 14   year 1   1200 grams
5    var x  week 15   year 1    700 grams
6    var y  week 16   year 1   1000 grams
7    var x  week 10   year 2    500 grams
8    var y  week 10   year 2    700 grams
9    var x  week 13   year 2   1300 grams
```

You can get quantiles from R's `summary` function. However, you need an additional package to calculate kurtosis and skewness. First, type the following command in your R console.

```
install.packages("moments")
```

Then you can run the following script

```
library(moments)

df$yield <- as.numeric(sub(" grams", "", df$yield)) # convert `yield` into a numeric vector
aggregate(
  yield ~ cultivar, data = df, 
  function(x) c(summary(x), skewness = skewness(x), kurtosis = kurtosis(x))
)
```

Output

```
  cultivar   yield.Min. yield.1st Qu. yield.Median   yield.Mean yield.3rd Qu.   yield.Max. yield.skewness yield.kurtosis
1    var x  500.0000000   600.0000000  700.0000000  820.0000000  1000.0000000 1300.0000000      0.5692290      1.8333916
2    var y  700.0000000   812.5000000  925.0000000  937.5000000  1050.0000000 1200.0000000      0.1684715      1.7088259
```

Comment: This is so cool, thanks for your help!

Is there a way to express quantiles in weeks, so I know that 25% of year 1 total harvest is done by week x , 50% by week y (median) and 75% by week z ?

Comment: I need some clarification here. AFAIK, 50% of the total harvest in year 1 is not equal to the median weekly yield. For example, if the yields are 30, 40, 50, 60 and 70 in respective weeks of year 1, then the median is 50 but 50% of the total harvest is 125. What do you want exactly? @OliC

Comment: Hi Ekoam, Thanks once again.

Let's simplify it:

if you have

var x , week 1 , 100 grams
var x , week 2 , 200 grams
var x , week 3 , 300 grams
var x , week 4 , 200 grams
var x , week 5 , 100 grams    

Plot weeks in the x axis and yield in the y axis.

The questions are: What is the interquartile range in weeks? What is the median week? what is the Kurtosis? What are the quantiles?...

If you think about it, this could be a histogram where every gram of yield falls in a category (week) so I don't see why we couldn't get those values... I just don't see how...

Comment: In your example, IQR is 100,  1st quantile is 200, and 3rd quantile is 300. However, you have two weeks with 200 grams yields. Then which week do you want to show? Also, if there are, for example, 6 weeks with the following yields: 100, 200, 300, 174, 100, 100, then IQR becomes 93.5, 3rd quantile becomes 193.5 and 1st quantile is 100. Then how can you map IQR or 3rd quantile to a week? @OliC

Comment: Sorry if I don't explain myself well. Let's put it differently:
the way I visualize it (theoretically) is a histogram (or its corresonding Gaussian bell) where x=weeks (ordered) and y=yield. 

the question is what is x when y = 25% of total yield ? and 50% and 75%? @ekoam

Comment: I think you misunderstand what is a histogram/distribution. The "histogram" you imagined is just a plot of yield against week. It's in fact a simple bar chart, not a histogram. A histogram measures the frequency or probability (y-axis) of some outcomes (x-axis). If you take your yield-week plot as a histogram, then a bar (13, 200) will be interpreted as that an outcome "week 13" has happened 200 times, not that the yield is 200 grams in week 13. Since what you want is not a histogram/distribution, using IQR, kurtosis or skewness is just pointless.

Comment: Also see [this](https://www.forbes.com/sites/naomirobbins/2012/01/04/a-histogram-is-not-a-bar-chart/?sh=2b2a95ea6d77) for detailed explanations on the difference between a histogram and bar chart. @OliC

Comment: oh ok, yes I might be confused. Thanks for your time anyway